# What are the typical ranges of voice types?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

One of the defining features of voice types are the typical ranges and while not the deciding factor, is a good indicator of what voice type a person is.

So what are the typical ranges of the main voice types including Soprano, Alto, Tenor, and Bass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An important distinction to be made here is the difference between **range** and **tessitura**. According to *The Complete Musician* by Steve Laitz,

> **range** is the total span of pitches that a voice can sing; this covers roughly the interval of a twelfth. ... a more comfortable register [is] referred to as its tessitura.

Laitz then provides a chart of SATB ranges and tessituras, reproduced below. "R" indicates range, while "T" indicates tessitura.

[image]

Most theory textbooks agree, but there are occasional differences. Note that these textbooks all only discuss the range, not the tessitura:

- *Tonal Harmony* by Kostka and Payne only has one difference: the lowest pitch of the bass is listed as E, not D. The same is true for *Harmony in Context* by Roig-Francolí.
- *The Complete Musician* by Clendinning and Marvin has the entire bass range moved up a step, from E to D instead of Laitz's D to C.
- *Harmony and Voice Leading* by Aldwell and Schachter has a few differences: the soprano can be extended by one step in both directions; the alto is listed as G to C, with the D an allowable extension; the tenor has a high A as an allowable extension; and the bass is listed as E to C, with both the lower and upper Ds allowed as extensions.
- *Harmonic Practice in Tonal Music* by Gauldin prefers D to F for the soprano, A to C for the alto, D to F for the tenor, and G to C for the bass. He lists one pitch above and below each range as an allowable extension.

Comment: I thought that *tessitura* was more applicable to the *range of notes in a piece*. Or maybe *excessive number of notes at the extremes of the range*.  Thus, a piece with a high tessitura would contain quite a few high notes - thus making it not easily sung by someone from that category. Obviously, some singers will vary slightly, so that some tenors, for example, would be able to comfortably sing a tenor piece with a low tessitura,which other tenors might not. Is Laitz stating *tessitura* is more a reference to voices (satb) than to the excessive number of high/middle/low notes that feature...

Comment: ...in a particular song? This may explain why in a/t/b/ the 'tessitura' is smaller than the range, but not so for top end sopranos. I'd have considered that tessitura refers to the song not the singer, and gives a better understanding to the poor soul who's about to sing. As in a bass may be quite capable and happy singing a song for tenor, providing it had a low tessitura, rather than him 'having a high tessitura'.

Comment: @Tim In my experience, the range of notes in a piece is typically referred to as the *ambitus*. But perhaps that's a US/UK distinction?

Comment: In a vague sort of way, tessitura can be construed as ambitus - which is a new one on me. Question time?

Comment: Why is baritone not included in this chart?

Comment: @user32882 Only because the prompt in the original question specifically addressed soprano, alto, tenor, and bass. They seemed to be asking about ranges for four-part voice leading, not all vocal ranges.

Comment: The chart is puzzling.  There is very little music written for bass voice that remains below C4.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to my Musescore program on my PC, the voices are listed as:

Female voices:

- **Soprano** (High) - Untrained: C4-G5, Trained: C4-C6
- **Mezzo-soprano** (Medium) - Untrained: A3-F5, Trained: A3-A5
- **Alto** (Low) - Untrained: G3-E5, Trained: E3-F5

Male voices:

- **Tenor** (High) - Untrained: C3-A4, Trained: C3-C5
- **Baritone** (Medium) - Untrained: G2-E4, Trained: F2-F4
- **Bass** (Low) - Untrained: F2-C4, Trained: D2-D4

Comment: where is that information from?